# Error al referenciar tablas en laravel al hacer migracion

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema al migrar la db por una referencia entre dos tablas en error que me envia es.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `peliculas`.`statuses` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `statuses` add constraint `statuses_type_status_id_foreign` foreign key (`type_status_id`) references `type_statuses` (`id`))
```

y las tablas en laravel son las siguientes tengo creando primero la type_statuses ya que no tiene foranea y la siguiente es la de statuses que es la que tiene la foranea para referenciar con type_statuses pero no entiendo por que me da el error.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->char('name', 20);
            $table->unsignedInteger('type_status_id');
            $table->foreign('type_status_id')->references('id')->on('type_statuses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('type_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->char('name', 20);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Pues muchas veces se pone database.tabla es normal por que tabla peliculas no tengo la db es la que se llama peliculas por eso sale -> peliculas.statuses que indica la tabla statuses en la db peliculas.

Comment: Que versión de Laravel estás usando?

Comment: Tal vez agregando unsigned al final, deberias tenerlo asi $table->integer('type_status_id')->unsigned(); o puedes poner $table->unsignedInteger('type_status_id'): para crear una restriccion de clave foranea, segun la documentacion de laravel

Comment: Hola @FelipeUrcia asi ya lo hice de esas dos maneras pero sigue dandome el mismo error

Comment: @BetaM la version de laravel que estoy usando es: 7.26.1

Comment: Ok tu problema es por los tipos de datos, por defecto Laravel esta usando `bigint` en las llaveas primarias  entonces tu columna de llave foránea debe ser `unsignedBigInteger` con eso debe quedar

Comment: Lo mismo de Beta, por la version es bigint, eso deberia solucionarlo.

Comment: Siempre revisa la doc. es muy didáctica y viene con ejemplos, aqui mira: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints si no me falla la memoria el cambio de `int` a `bigint` ocurrió desde la 5.8

Comment: Eso además de que la migración que crea `type_statuses` se debe crear primero que la de `statuses`

Comment: @BetaM si asi esta como dices primero se crea la que no tiene llave foranea como estas diciendo esta el orden para que se creen

Comment: Yo ahí veo un tipo de dato distinto

Comment: Ya lo hice poniendo id en integer y lo mismo en la otra tabla que las dos columnas de la que se referencia queden en integer las dos pero aun asi me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Edita y agrega como lo modificaste por qué me late que me entendiste mal

Comment: @BetaM asi lo deje me di cuenta que a la db estaban llegando como bigint ya los puse en unsignedInteger el de la tb statuses y en la tb type_statuses puse que el id fuera integer pero aun asi sigue el mismo error ya edite arriba el codigo.

Comment: Cuál de esas dos migraciones estás ejecutando primero?

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe que, a la hora de que laravel intenta recolectar la FK y la PK, necesita que existan, sino, genera un error.

En este caso, necesitas una FK que se llame `type_status_id` el cual se crea despues de crearse la tabla statuses. Te recomiendo que, hagas lo siguiente:

Hacer un alter table a tu tabla statuses para agregar el campo `type_status_id`

```
php artisan make:migration add_to_type_status_id_to_statuses_table --table=statuses
```

En este nuevo archivo, agregas la `type_status_id`, de tal modo que tus tablas quedarian de la siguiente manera:

`statuses table`

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->char('name', 20);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('type_status_id');
    
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

`type_statuses table`

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('type_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->char('name', 20);
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

y tu archivo `add_to_type_status_id_to_statuses_table`

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('type_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('type_status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
  }
}
```

A tener en cuenta, Si estas usando laravel 7, te recomiendo dejar el campo `$table->id()` por defecto, ya que, puedes usar tranquilamente el dato `unsignedBigInteger` para el casteo.

Mas informacion en la [Documentacion de laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations)

Si tienes algun problema, aqui estamos.